# How do I force npm dependencies using npm-force-resolutions without using npx?

Tags: node.js, npm

I need to force a specific package version in a nested dependency. For something like this, `npm-force-resolutions` works great. A typical solution is to add the `script` `"preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"` and `"resolutions": {}` with a list of package names as keys and versions as values.

For example, if we had a nested dependency of `node-fetch` at `^1.7.3`, but we needed it at `^2.6.1`, an extracted `package.json` script might look like this:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that for security reasons in my environment, I don't have access to `npx`. A solution I tried to come up with was to install `npm-force-resolutions` as a dev dependency, then add `./node_modules/.bin/npm-force-resolutions` as a `postinstall` `script` in the `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/npm-force-resolutions"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

Sadly, after running `npm install`, the resolutions were not updated (in the above example, `node-fetch` was still at `^1.7.3`). Once `npm` was finished installing all packages, however, running `./node_modules/.bin/npm-force-resolutions` manually *does* force the resolutions as expected (changing `node-fetch` above from `^1.7.3` to `^2.6.1`).

Is there a way to force resolutions *within* the install lifecycle but *without* calling `npx`? It is important it happens within a single call to `npm install` due to involvement in continuous integration.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's not the best solution, but you can try installing that dependency and running it in the preinstall hook instead of running npx:

```
"preinstall": "npm i npm-force-resolutions && ./node_modules/.bin/npm-force-resolutions",
```